# JSON data with configurable options in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, regex, json, angularjs, database-design

> Project available on https://github.com/s-d-le/flex-form

I'm working on a piece of Angular app. It is intended to work as a questionaire form. The questions will be shown in sequence. What question 2 asks will depend on the choice users make in question 1.
I setup 3 simple json files

```
{
    "questions" : 
    [
        {"id" : 1, "child" : 2, "step" : 1, "question" : "My name is [user]", "inputType" : "text"},
        {"id" : 2, "child" : 4, "step" : 1, "question" : "I live by myself [none]", "inputType" : "none"},
        {"id" : 3, "child" : 5, "step" : 1, "question" : "I live with [animals]", "inputType" : "option"},
        {"id" : 4, "child" : 7, "step" : 2, "question" : "I would like to adopt [animals]", "inputType" : "option"},
        {"id" : 5, "child" : 6, "step" : 2, "question" : "My [animals] is [animals_year] old", "inputType" : "option"},
        {"id" : 6, "child" : 0, "step" : 3, "question" : "My [animals] is [sizes]", "inputType" : "option"},
        {"id" : 7, "child" : 0, "step" : 3, "question" : "I like [sizes] [animals]", "inputType" : "option"}
    ]
}

{
    "animals" : 
    [
        {"id" : 1, "option" : "cat"},
        {"id" : 2, "option" : "dog"},
        {"id" : 3, "option" : "panda"}
    ]
}
{
"sizes" : 
[
    {"id" : 1, "option" : "small"},
    {"id" : 2, "option" : "medium"},
    {"id" : 3, "option" : "large"}
]}
```

*These are 3 separate JSON files (questions.json, animals.json and sizes.json)

I will explain how I setup the logic in Angular:
Lets say we are dealing with: `I live with [animals] | type:option.` We use JS RegEx to get:

```
a = 'I live with'; //pure text

b = 'animals'; //whatever between brackets will be used for the next http.get

And we pre write the HTML element of type:option
c = '<select>**TO DO**</selection>'
```

Then we make a new `http.get(b + '.json')` to get the options (b is going to animals)
Next we throw those option into the pre written HTML

```
c = '<select>
        option:dog
        option:cat
        option:panda
    </select>'
```

**In short**: I break down the content in questions.json to pure text and the keys to select options. These keys are used to query the option tables.The options (in json format) will be pushed into an array and displayed on the view.

By far, I have been able to RegEx, filter and extract the data to the smallest unit. I have something like these:

```
$scope.filtered.pureText //an array contains the pure text
$scope.filtered.inBrackets //an array contains the key option between []
$scope.optionData //an array contains the option data after the json call
```

My questions are:
Is it the best way to set up your data (questions.json) for sub-queries to other tables?
How can I construct the `<select><option>...</option></select>` with the data from the animals and sizes table. And place these select boxes into the questions accordingly. Example:

```
I live with [animals]
becomes
<div>I live with
    <select>
        <option>Cat</option>
        <option>Dog</option>
        <option>Penguin</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice explanation . . but it would be better if you could add a fiddle

Comment: thank you I have added the code I ve been working on so far on jsfiddle